# Is there a way to run `dotnet nuget` with a specific version of nuget?

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget

I am doing some research and was trying to find out if it's possible to run `dotnet nuget` with a specific nuget version? I need to run some tests against different versions of nuget under linux and was hoping I could use [`dotnet-docker`](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/3.0/sdk/alpine3.10/amd64/Dockerfile) and run them in a docker container.

I am aware I can run it with `mono`, but there are a lot of times when `mono` is problematic under different distributions. I would prefer using the official dotnet docker image if that's possible.

Comment: .NET Core CLI does not ship with a full NuGet client, nor allow you to override that client, so I assume the answer is No.

Comment: Ahh... that's too bad! I guess I'm stuck with mono then. Would you like to add an answer so I can mark it?